# Select <figure> when it contains <iframe>

Tags: html, css

How to select `<figure>` only when it contains `<iframe>`?

I need to select this `figure`:

```
<figure>
   <iframe></iframe>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class:

```css
figure:has(iframe) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  With iframe
  <iframe></iframe>
</figure>
<figure>
  With image
  <img>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :not selector:

````
figure:not(:empty):not(:has(img)) {
  /* Your styles here */
}```
````

Comment: Probably better as `figure:has(iframe):not(:has(img))` instead of `:not(:empty)`

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase my question. I'm sure there must be simpler solution. How can I select all <figures> that contain an <iframe>?

Comment: Exactly what @DanielBeck's answer does ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
figure:has(iframe)
```

does this trick

The CSS :has selector helps you select elements that contain elements that match the selector you pass into the :has() function. It’s essentially a “parent” selector, although far more useful than just that. For example, imagine being able to select all `<div>`s but only when they contain a `<p>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Can I Use states "Since December 2023, this feature works across the latest devices and major browser versions"

Comment: Imho, this is not very honest to modify your initial question, in order to give yourself a trivial answer :/

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I didn't know about :has() so it wasn't a "trivial" answer to me. I only modified my question when it became apperant it needed modifying. I don't think I benefit from answering my own question? And that certainly wasn't my intention. I've answered so that others can see the :has() code.